# Which is the best spring boot dependency to use with postgis?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, postgis

I'm new with PostGIS and trying to figure out which are the more appropriate dependencies to use with in a Spring Boot/PostGIS project.

I'm starting with https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.postgis/postgis-jdbc. But don't know if anyone could give me some other recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maven GroupId `net.postgis` is from the creators of PostGis.

`org.postgis` is a consulting company.

So your dependency is the right one.